# Generating all permutations efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, permutation

I need to generate as fast as possible all [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of integers `0`, `1`, `2`, `...`, `n - 1` and have result as a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array of shape `(factorial(n), n)`, or to iterate through large portions of such an array to conserve memory.

Is there some built-in function in NumPy for doing this? Or some combination of functions.

Using `itertools.permutations(...)` is too slow, I need a faster method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a NumPy solution that builds the permutations of size m by modifying the permutations of size m-1 (see more explanation further down):

```
def permutations(n):
    a = np.zeros((np.math.factorial(n), n), np.uint8)
    f = 1
    for m in range(2, n+1):
        b = a[:f, n-m+1:]      # the block of permutations of range(m-1)
        for i in range(1, m):
            a[i*f:(i+1)*f, n-m] = i
            a[i*f:(i+1)*f, n-m+1:] = b + (b >= i)
        b += 1
        f *= m
    return a
```

Demo:

```
>>> permutations(3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

For n=10, the itertools solution takes 5.5 seconds for me while this NumPy solution takes 0.2 seconds.

How it proceeds: It starts with a zero-array of the goal size, which already contains the permutations for `range(1)` at the top-right (I "dotted out" the other parts of the array):

```
[[. . 0]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]]
```

Then it turns that into the permutations of `range(2)`:

```
[[. 0 1]
 [. 1 0]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]
 [. . .]]
```

And then into the permutations of `range(3)`:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 2 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [1 2 0]
 [2 0 1]
 [2 1 0]]
```

It does so by filling the next-left column and by copying/modifying the previous block of permutations downwards.

Comment: Very nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Arty Can you tell how fast it is for you compared to your Numba solutions? At repl.it they seem to be similar, with the fastest Numba solution being a bit faster. I think I could improve mine a tiny bit by growing from the *bottom*-right corner instead of the top-right corner, as the bottom-right corner remains as it is and thus wouldn't need the `b += 1`.

Comment: Simplicity is also very important. In fact that is exactly what I wanted - to have pure numpy solution, not to carry Numba beast around or binary compiled `.so`/`.pyd` module. If they differ `5%-30%` in speed that is totally alright.

Comment: As pointed out by @DanielGiger [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231033/941531) if you make your array transposed then your code will be twice faster due to cache locality. Just replace `a = np.zeros((np.math.factorial(n), n), np.uint8)` with `a = np.zeros((n, np.math.factorial(n)), np.uint8).T` and code will be almost twice faster.

Comment: Just did time measurements. Your solution on `n=10` gives time almost identical to my Numba solution. And after suggestion of @DanielGiger (described in my previous comment above) your improved code takes about 60% of time of my Numba solution, so around 1.8x times faster. You may run code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64291077/941531), just today I added time comparisons with your solution (with @DanielGieger improvements), so you can see it compared to my Numba code. You may run timings till `n=10` in my code, because `n=11` takes too long time in itertools.

Answer (score 6):

#### Update: faster version

This solution is about 5x faster than my original answer, due to avoiding unnecessary computation.  This approach builds an array by expanding from one corner, using the same basic idea explained in [superb rain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341432/6338179), but is much faster since it avoids unnecessary work.

```
def faster_permutations(n):
    # empty() is fast because it does not initialize the values of the array
    # order='F' uses Fortran ordering, which makes accessing elements in the same column fast
    perms = np.empty((np.math.factorial(n), n), dtype=np.uint8, order='F')
    perms[0, 0] = 0

    rows_to_copy = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        perms[:rows_to_copy, i] = i
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            start_row = rows_to_copy * j
            end_row = rows_to_copy * (j + 1)
            splitter = i - j
            perms[start_row: end_row, splitter] = i
            perms[start_row: end_row, :splitter] = perms[:rows_to_copy, :splitter]  # left side
            perms[start_row: end_row, splitter + 1:i + 1] = perms[:rows_to_copy, splitter:i]  # right side

        rows_to_copy *= i + 1

    return perms
```

Timings on my machine with `n=11`:

```
faster_permutations():                          0.12 seconds 
permutations() [superb rain's approach]:        1.44 seconds
permutations() with memory order optimization:  0.62 seconds
```

---

#### Original Answer:

Based on [superb rain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341432/6338179), this is a faster version with more efficient memory access patterns:

```
def fast_permutations(n):
    a = np.zeros((n, np.math.factorial(n)), np.uint8)
    f = 1
    for m in range(2, n + 1):
        b = a[n - m + 1:, :f]  # the block of permutations of range(m-1)
        for i in range(1, m):
            a[n - m, i * f:(i + 1) * f] = i
            a[n - m + 1:, i * f:(i + 1) * f] = b + (b >= i)
        b += 1
        f *= m
    return a.T
```

This is essentially the transpose of superb rain's version.  It's more efficient because the memory locations accessed are closer together.

On my machine, it's about 2x as fast as the original version (0.05 seconds vs 0.12 seconds for `n=10`).

Comment: Thanks! Up-Voted. Can you also please do timings for longer time period? 3-5 seconds at least instead of `0.05` seconds like you did? I.e. set bigger `n`.

Comment: On my machine for `n=11` superbrain's version gives 6.7 seconds and yours gives 3.5 seconds. So indeed your solution looks faster. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, to apply your transpose idea to superbrain's code it is also possible by just replacing just single line `a = np.zeros((np.math.factorial(n), n), np.uint8)` with `a = np.zeros((n, np.math.factorial(n)), np.uint8).T` in his original code.

Answer (score 4):

As I didn't find a good/fast-enough solution, I decided to implement whole permutations algorithm from scratch using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)/[AOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) code compiler/optimizer.

My next numba-based solution is `25x-50x` times faster for large enough `n` than doing same task using `itertools.permutations(...)`. See timings after code.

If iterating by 1 permutation at a time my code is just `1.25x` faster than `itertools.permutations(...)`, but according to initial question I needed either whole array of all permutations or at least iterating over large chunks.

I've implemented possibility to both use numba and no-numba mode and both JIT and AOT variants in numba mode. Also it is possible to choose whether to iterate by one permutation at a time (`iter_ = True, iter_batches = False`) or by batch of permutations at a time which is much faster (`iter_ = True, iter_batches = True`) or to return whole array of all permutations without iteration (`iter_ = False`). Also it is possible to tweak batch size e.g. by `batch_size = 1000`.

Central internal function is `next_batch(...)` which actually implements whole algorithm of generating next permutations given previous one. It is the only JITed/AOTed by numba function, the rest are helper pure-Python wrappers.

My timings are not very precise as my laptop's CPU slows down at random points of time `2.2x` times when over-heated (which happens often).

Today (2022.02.23) added also timings of [superbrain's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341432/941531) with improvements [suggested by @DanielGieger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231033/941531). It appeared to have about same time as my Numba solution (if to take without improvements) and about 1.8x times faster than Numba if to use improvements of @DanielGieger.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64291076#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numba numpy timerit

def permutations(
    n, *, iter_ = True, numba_ = True, numba_aot = False,
    batch_size = 1000, iter_batches = False, state = {},
):
    key = (bool(numba_), bool(numba_aot))
    
    if key in state:
        return state[key](int(n), bool(iter_), int(batch_size), bool(iter_batches))
        
    def prepare(numba_, numba_aot):
        import numpy as np
        
        def next_batch(a, r):
            c, n = r.shape[0], r.shape[1]
            for ic in range(c):
                r[ic] = a
                a = r[ic]
                for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
                    if a[i] < a[i + 1]:
                        break
                else:
                    assert False # Already last permutation
                for j in range(n - 1, i, -1):
                    if a[i] < a[j]:
                        break
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
                for k in range(1, (n - i + 1) >> 1):
                    a[i + k], a[n - k] = a[n - k], a[i + k]
            
        def factorial(n):
            res = 1
            for i in range(2, n + 1):
                res *= i
            return res
            
        def permutations_iter(nxb, n, batch_size, iter_batches):
            a = np.arange(n, dtype = np.uint8)
            if iter_batches:
                yield a[None, :]
            else:
                yield a
            if n <= 1:
                return
            total = factorial(n)
            for i in range(1, total, batch_size):
                batch = np.empty((min(batch_size, total - i), n), dtype = np.uint8)
                nxb(a, batch)
                if iter_batches:
                    yield batch
                else:
                    yield from iter(batch)
                a = batch[-1]
        
        def permutations_arr(nxb, n, batch_size):
            total = factorial(n)
            res = np.empty((total, n), dtype = np.uint8)
            res[0] = np.arange(n, dtype = np.uint8)
            for i in range(1, total, batch_size):
                nxb(res[i - 1], res[i : i + min(batch_size, total - i)])
            return res

        if not numba_:
            return lambda n, it, bs, ib: permutations_iter(next_batch, n, bs, ib) if it else permutations_arr(next_batch, n, bs)
        else:
            if not numba_aot:
                import numba
                nxb = numba.njit('void(u1[:], u1[:, :])', cache = True)(next_batch)
            else:
                import numba, numba.pycc
                cc = numba.pycc.CC('permutations_numba')
                cc.export('next_batch', 'void(u1[:], u1[:, :])')(next_batch)
                cc.compile()
                from permutations_numba import next_batch as nxb
                
            return lambda n, it, bs, ib: permutations_iter(nxb, n, bs, ib) if it else permutations_arr(nxb, n, bs)
            
    state[key] = prepare(numba_, numba_aot)
    return state[key](int(n), bool(iter_), int(batch_size), bool(iter_batches))

def test():
    import numpy as np, itertools
    from timerit import Timerit
    
    Timerit._default_asciimode = True

    # Heat-up / pre-compile
    permutations(2, numba_ = False)
    permutations(2, numba_ = True)

    for n in range(12):
        num = 99 if n <= 7 else 15 if n <= 8 else 3 if n <= 9 else 1
        print('-' * 60 + f'\nn = {str(n).rjust(2)}')

        print(f'itertools          : ', end = '', flush = True)
        for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
            with t:
                ref = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(n))), dtype = np.uint8)
                
        def superbrain(n):
            a = np.zeros((n, np.math.factorial(n)), np.uint8).T
            f = 1
            for m in range(2, n+1):
                b = a[:f, n-m+1:]      # the block of permutations of range(m-1)
                for i in range(1, m):
                    a[i*f:(i+1)*f, n-m] = i
                    a[i*f:(i+1)*f, n-m+1:] = b + (b >= i)
                b += 1
                f *= m
            return a

        print(f'superbrain         : ', end = '', flush = True)
        for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
            with t:
                cur = superbrain(n)
            assert np.array_equal(ref, cur)

        if n <= 9:
            print(f'python_array       : ', end = '', flush = True)
            for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
                with t:
                    curpa = permutations(n, iter_ = False, numba_ = False)
                assert np.array_equal(ref, curpa)
        
        for batch_size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
            print(f'batch_size = {str(batch_size).rjust(5)}')
        
            print(f'numba_iter         : ', end = '', flush = True)
            for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
                with t:
                    curi = np.array(list(permutations(n, iter_ = True, numba_ = True, batch_size = batch_size)))
                assert np.array_equal(ref, curi)
                
            print(f'numba_iter_batches : ', end = '', flush = True)
            for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
                with t:
                    curib = np.concatenate(list(permutations(n, iter_ = True, numba_ = True, batch_size = batch_size, iter_batches = True)))
                assert np.array_equal(ref, curib)

            print(f'numba_array        : ', end = '', flush = True)
            for t in Timerit(num = num, verbose = 1):
                with t:
                    cura = permutations(n, iter_ = False, numba_ = True, batch_size = batch_size)
                assert np.array_equal(ref, cura)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output (timings):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  0
itertools          : Timed best=8.210 us, mean=8.335 +- 0.4 us
python_array       : Timed best=14.881 us, mean=15.457 +- 0.5 us
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.126 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.447 us, mean=17.929 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=15.394 us, mean=15.519 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.250 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.447 us, mean=18.038 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=15.394 us, mean=15.519 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.328 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.960 us, mean=18.069 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=15.394 us, mean=15.441 +- 0.1 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.328 +- 0.2 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.448 us, mean=17.976 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=14.881 us, mean=15.410 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  1
itertools          : Timed best=7.697 us, mean=7.790 +- 0.3 us
python_array       : Timed best=14.882 us, mean=15.488 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.064 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.960 us, mean=18.318 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=14.881 us, mean=15.348 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.203 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.960 us, mean=18.054 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=15.394 us, mean=15.472 +- 0.2 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.421 +- 0.1 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.960 us, mean=18.147 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=14.882 us, mean=15.379 +- 0.2 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=15.908 us, mean=16.095 +- 0.2 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=17.960 us, mean=18.132 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=14.881 us, mean=15.395 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  2
itertools          : Timed best=8.723 us, mean=8.786 +- 0.2 us
python_array       : Timed best=29.250 us, mean=29.670 +- 0.4 us
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=34.381 us, mean=35.035 +- 0.7 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=30.276 us, mean=30.790 +- 0.4 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.579 us, mean=22.672 +- 0.2 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=34.381 us, mean=34.584 +- 0.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=30.277 us, mean=30.836 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.066 us, mean=22.595 +- 0.2 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=34.381 us, mean=34.739 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=30.277 us, mean=30.851 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.579 us, mean=22.626 +- 0.1 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=34.381 us, mean=34.786 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=30.276 us, mean=30.650 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.066 us, mean=22.641 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  3
itertools          : Timed best=12.829 us, mean=13.093 +- 0.3 us
python_array       : Timed best=62.606 us, mean=63.461 +- 0.6 us
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=39.513 us, mean=40.120 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=31.302 us, mean=31.661 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.579 us, mean=23.077 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=39.513 us, mean=40.042 +- 0.2 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=31.302 us, mean=31.629 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.579 us, mean=23.154 +- 0.2 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=39.513 us, mean=39.840 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=31.302 us, mean=31.629 +- 0.4 us
numba_array        : Timed best=22.579 us, mean=23.170 +- 0.2 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=39.513 us, mean=40.120 +- 0.5 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=30.789 us, mean=31.412 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=23.092 us, mean=23.232 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  4
itertools          : Timed best=34.381 us, mean=34.911 +- 0.4 us
python_array       : Timed best=207.830 us, mean=209.152 +- 1.0 us
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=82.619 us, mean=83.054 +- 0.7 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=44.645 us, mean=44.754 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=31.302 us, mean=31.458 +- 0.2 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=63.632 us, mean=64.036 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=32.329 us, mean=32.889 +- 0.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=24.118 us, mean=24.600 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=63.632 us, mean=64.083 +- 0.5 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=32.329 us, mean=32.904 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=24.118 us, mean=24.569 +- 0.3 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=63.119 us, mean=63.927 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=32.329 us, mean=32.889 +- 0.5 us
numba_array        : Timed best=24.118 us, mean=24.461 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  5
itertools          : Timed best=156.001 us, mean=166.311 +- 20.5 us
python_array       : Timed best=0.999 ms, mean=1.002 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=293.528 us, mean=294.461 +- 0.8 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=102.632 us, mean=103.254 +- 0.4 us
numba_array        : Timed best=64.145 us, mean=64.985 +- 0.5 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=198.080 us, mean=199.107 +- 0.8 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=44.132 us, mean=44.894 +- 0.4 us
numba_array        : Timed best=33.355 us, mean=33.884 +- 0.3 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=186.791 us, mean=187.522 +- 0.4 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=37.973 us, mean=38.471 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=29.763 us, mean=30.183 +- 0.3 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=186.790 us, mean=187.646 +- 0.7 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=37.974 us, mean=38.534 +- 0.3 us
numba_array        : Timed best=29.763 us, mean=30.245 +- 0.3 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  6
itertools          : Timed best=0.991 ms, mean=1.007 +- 0.0 ms
python_array       : Timed best=5.873 ms, mean=6.012 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=1.668 ms, mean=1.673 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=503.411 us, mean=506.506 +- 1.2 us
numba_array        : Timed best=293.015 us, mean=296.047 +- 1.2 us
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=1.036 ms, mean=1.145 +- 0.3 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=120.593 us, mean=132.878 +- 23.0 us
numba_array        : Timed best=93.908 us, mean=97.438 +- 2.4 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=962.178 us, mean=976.624 +- 23.9 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=78.001 us, mean=82.992 +- 7.7 us
numba_array        : Timed best=68.250 us, mean=69.852 +- 4.3 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=963.717 us, mean=977.044 +- 27.3 us
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=77.487 us, mean=80.084 +- 7.5 us
numba_array        : Timed best=68.250 us, mean=69.634 +- 4.4 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  7
itertools          : Timed best=8.502 ms, mean=8.579 +- 0.0 ms
python_array       : Timed best=41.690 ms, mean=42.358 +- 0.8 ms
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=11.523 ms, mean=11.646 +- 0.2 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=3.407 ms, mean=3.497 +- 0.1 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=1.944 ms, mean=1.975 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=7.050 ms, mean=7.397 +- 0.3 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=659.925 us, mean=668.198 +- 5.9 us
numba_array        : Timed best=503.411 us, mean=506.086 +- 3.3 us
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=6.576 ms, mean=6.630 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=382.305 us, mean=389.707 +- 4.4 us
numba_array        : Timed best=354.081 us, mean=360.364 +- 4.3 us
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=6.463 ms, mean=6.504 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=349.976 us, mean=352.091 +- 1.5 us
numba_array        : Timed best=330.989 us, mean=337.194 +- 1.8 us
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  8
itertools          : Timed best=71.003 ms, mean=71.824 +- 0.5 ms
python_array       : Timed best=331.176 ms, mean=339.746 +- 7.3 ms
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=99.929 ms, mean=101.098 +- 1.3 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=27.489 ms, mean=27.905 +- 0.3 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=15.370 ms, mean=15.560 +- 0.1 ms
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=62.168 ms, mean=62.765 +- 0.7 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=5.083 ms, mean=5.119 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=3.824 ms, mean=3.842 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=57.706 ms, mean=57.935 +- 0.2 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=2.824 ms, mean=2.832 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=2.656 ms, mean=2.670 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=57.457 ms, mean=60.128 +- 2.1 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=2.615 ms, mean=2.635 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=2.550 ms, mean=2.565 +- 0.0 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
n =  9
itertools          : Timed best=724.017 ms, mean=724.017 +- 0.0 ms
python_array       : Timed best=3.071 s, mean=3.071 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=950.892 ms, mean=950.892 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=261.376 ms, mean=261.376 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=145.207 ms, mean=145.207 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=584.761 ms, mean=584.761 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=50.632 ms, mean=50.632 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=39.945 ms, mean=39.945 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=535.190 ms, mean=535.190 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=29.557 ms, mean=29.557 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=26.541 ms, mean=26.541 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=533.592 ms, mean=533.592 +- 0.0 ms
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=27.507 ms, mean=27.507 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=25.115 ms, mean=25.115 +- 0.0 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
n = 10
itertools          : Timed best=15.483 s, mean=15.483 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=24.163 s, mean=24.163 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=6.039 s, mean=6.039 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=3.246 s, mean=3.246 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=13.891 s, mean=13.891 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=1.136 s, mean=1.136 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=890.228 ms, mean=890.228 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=12.768 s, mean=12.768 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=693.685 ms, mean=693.685 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=658.007 ms, mean=658.007 +- 0.0 ms
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=11.175 s, mean=11.175 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=278.304 ms, mean=278.304 +- 0.0 ms
numba_array        : Timed best=251.208 ms, mean=251.208 +- 0.0 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
n = 11
itertools          : Timed best=95.118 s, mean=95.118 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =    10
numba_iter         : Timed best=124.414 s, mean=124.414 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=75.427 s, mean=75.427 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=28.079 s, mean=28.079 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =   100
numba_iter         : Timed best=70.749 s, mean=70.749 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=6.084 s, mean=6.084 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=4.357 s, mean=4.357 +- 0.0 s
batch_size =  1000
numba_iter         : Timed best=67.576 s, mean=67.576 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=8.572 s, mean=8.572 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=6.915 s, mean=6.915 +- 0.0 s
batch_size = 10000
numba_iter         : Timed best=123.208 s, mean=123.208 +- 0.0 s
numba_iter_batches : Timed best=3.348 s, mean=3.348 +- 0.0 s
numba_array        : Timed best=2.789 s, mean=2.789 +- 0.0 s
```

Comment: If your CPU slows down randomly due to heat, maybe just run it at 50% speed all the time during the benchmark?

Comment: @superbrain At least I don't know how to control my cpu speed. Maybe I need some utilities to be installed for them, or there are Windows built in tools. But I never did this before so I don't know how to slow down my cpu intentionally.

Comment: I've done it by creating a new power plan where I set "Minimum processor state" and "Maximum processor state" all to 80%.