# Create all permutations of size N of the digits 0-9 - as optimized as possible using numpy\scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i need to create an array of all the permutations of the digits 0-9 of size N (input, 1 <= N <= 10).

I've tried this:

```
np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(10), n)))
```

for n=6:

```
timeit np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(10), 6)))
```

on my machine gives:

```
68.5 ms ± 881 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

But it simply not fast enough.
I need it to be below 40ms.

Note:
I cannot change the machine from numpy version 1.22.3

Comment: How much too slow is it, and what do  you need this for?

Comment: With `numpy >=1.23` using `np.fromiter(itertools.permutations(range(10), 6), dtype=np.dtype((np.int8, 6)))` is ~2x faster on my 2-core machine.

Comment: Is N=6 the largest you need? If you need larger, what are the time limits for those?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That sounds promising, but when I run your code I get the error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: @JohnColeman - Which `numpy` version?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny 
On numpy 1.22.3 (which i cannot change)
I get: 
    np.fromiter(itertools.permutations(range(10), 6), dtype=list)
ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator

Comment: @GuyBarash - `dtype` must define a suitable subarray for a 2D result, not `list`. It is only supported for `numpy 1.23` or newer.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny
Like this? 
gen = itertools.permutations(range(10), 6)
arr = np.fromiter(gen, dtype=np.ndarray)

Now i get: 
ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator

Comment: @GuyBarash - No, like I wrote in my comment `dtype=np.dtype((np.int8, 6))` and you **must** use `numpy >= 1.23`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny
I really can't change the numpy version. It's not in my control.
Any other solution for version 1.22.3?

Comment: It is easy to compute the size of the resulting array. Perhaps if you preallocate the array with zeros of the appropriate dtype you can then fill it with the permutations.

Comment: `np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(range(10), 6)), dtype=np.int8).reshape(-1, 6)` has triple acceleration on my machine.

Comment: @MechanicPig Perhaps you can make this an answer (with a nod to Michael Szczensky for the idea of using `fromiter()`)

Comment: @MechanicPig How about via `bytes`? `np.frombuffer(bytes(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(range(10), 6))), dtype=np.int8).reshape(-1, 6)`. faster for me, but I can only test on old Python/NumPy. Anyway, I'm still not convinced they need this at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy Surprisingly fast, it seems that numpy "wasted" a lot of time in `fromiter`.

Comment: @MechanicPig Or maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341432/12671057), not using itertools but building in NumPy. Not sure about how to do it for N<10, though, too sleepy to think about it ...

Comment: Still wondering why/whether you need this and how much time you allow for N>6 ...

Comment: @KellyBundy Bot programing competition. I have 50ms per turn

Comment: So 50ms for N=10 as well? And your bot must return an array with all those permutations? That's the end goal? You're not then processing the array further and only returning the result of *that*?

Comment: @KellyBundy
It's a game of Cows and Bulls (N digits to guess)
I start with every options and reduces the valid permutations. 

I got a pretty good score on my local simulator, but the competition machine is kind of crap and i have 50ms per turn (including the first)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291076/generating-all-permutations-efficiently/64341432#64341432) provided by @KellyBundy to get a fast method:

```
def permutations_(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return np.empty((1, 0), np.uint8)

    shape = (math.perm(n, k), k)
    out = np.zeros(shape, np.uint8)
    out[:n - k + 1, -1] = np.arange(n - k + 1, dtype=np.uint8)

    start = n - k + 1
    for col in reversed(range(1, k)):
        block = out[:start, col:]
        length = start
        for i in range(1, n - col + 1):
            stop = start + length
            out[start:stop, col:] = block + (block >= i)
            out[start:stop, col - 1] = i
            start = stop
        block += 1  # block is a sub-view on `out`

    return out
```

Simple test:

```
In [125]: %timeit permutations_(10, 6)
3.73 ms ± 30.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [128]: np.array_equal(permutations_(10, 6), np.array(list(permutations(range(10), 6))))
Out[128]: True
```

---

### Old answer

Using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to concatenate iterators of each tuple to construct array lazily can get a little improvement:

```
In [94]: from itertools import chain, permutations

In [95]: %timeit np.array(list(permutations(range(10), 6)), np.int8)
63.2 ms ± 500 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [96]: %timeit np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(permutations(range(10), 6)), np.int8).reshape(-1, 6)
28.4 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@KellyBundy proposed a faster solution in the comments area, using the fast iteration in the `bytes` constructor and buffer protocol. It seems that the `numpy.fromiter` wasted a lot of time in iteration:

```
In [98]: %timeit np.frombuffer(bytes(chain.from_iterable(permutations(range(10), 6))), np.int8).reshape(-1, 6)
11.3 ms ± 23.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However, it should be noted that the above results are read-only (thanks for @MichaelSzczesny's reminder):

```
In [109]: ar = np.frombuffer(bytes(chain.from_iterable(permutations(range(10), 6))), np.int8).reshape(-1, 6)

In [110]: ar[0, 0] = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [110], line 1
----> 1 ar[0, 0] = 1

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Comment: Nearly zero overhead to convert with `np.frombuffer` from `bytes` (can't measure it reliably since system noise is larger), this is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I subconsciously thought it would make copy. I use it too little.

Comment: Making a copy is super fast, though, right? (At least calling `.copy()` on the array takes almost no time for me.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Get a better answer through the link you provided ;-)

Comment: How about times for length 10? The new solution might have a bigger advantage there.

Comment: @KellyBundy More than 3 times faster than the `frombuffer` solution. At full length, my solution is almost the same as that in the link.